# Disable "View All" in RWD navigation menu

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

How do I disable "View All _" in the dropdown menu of the RWD theme in v1.9x?

Comment: Can you mark my answer as best? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable it by configuration.
You need to change renderer template or create new renderer template.

**1.** Change native tempalte

Open the file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`. Find the following section:

```
if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
    $html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .' view-all">';
    $html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
    $html .=             $this->__('View All') . ' ' . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
    $html .=         '</a>';
    $html .=     '</li>';
    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

and replace with

```
if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    $html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

**2.** Create custom template

Create copy of `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml` with new name. For example `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer-new.phtml`

then update layouts with renderer
*Catalog* layout
`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml` and *Page* layout `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml`

Find the following line

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
```

and replace with new template

```
<block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer-new.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Go to System->Configuration->Catalog (Left hand side).
- Click on catalog (under Catalog option)->select "Frontend" option.
- In Allow All Products per Page set to "No".
- Click on "Save Config" button.

Please let me know if you find any problem.